# Why do I see 3 node rings in the DSE OpsCenter

Tags: opscenter

Simple Newby question.
I've booted 3 instances up in EC2, a cassandra, solr and spark node.
I thought they would appear as a single clustered ring in the OpsCenter, but they actually appear as 3 separate rings with a single node in each.
Is this the expected behaviour, or have I done something stupid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the different workloads (database, solr, spark) each of your nodes is in a different DataCenter, and there is one ring for each. It is possible to have more than one workload type in one cluster but that requires some setup:

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/deploy/deployWkLdSep.html